Modular exponentiation in GF(2^8) using python
I am trying to  write the Python program for GF(2^8) exponentiation and verify the relationship:

Let in GF(2^8) exponentiation " a^b mod x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 = c ".

Now let 'd' be the multiplicative inverse of exponent 'b'.

Multiplicative inverse b.d mod x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1  = 1

I want to verify that "c^d mod x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 = a ".


def int_to_binary_array(n, length):
    # Convert integer n to a binary array of length 'length'
    return [int(x) for x in format(n, f'0{length}b')]

def binary_array_to_int(binary_array):
    # Convert binary array back to an integer
    result = 0
    for bit in binary_array:
        result = (result << 1) | bit
    return result

def decimal_to_binary_array(n, m=8):
    # Convert decimal integer n to binary array of length m
    return int_to_binary_array(n, m)

def gf_multiply_fma(A_array, B_array, P, F_array=None):
    """
    Perform multiplication and addition in GF(2^m) using the LSB-first bit serial algorithm.
    """
    A = binary_array_to_int(A_array)
    B = binary_array_to_int(B_array)
    F = binary_array_to_int(F_array) if F_array else 0

    T = F  # Initialize T with F for the Fused Multiply-Add (FMA) operation
    for i in range(8):  # We assume 8-bit for simplicity here
        if B & 1:   # if LSB of B is 1
            T ^= A      # xor T with A
        B >>= 1         # right shift B for next LSB
        A <<= 1         # left shift A for next step of multiplication
        if A & 0b100000000:  # checking if A is greater than x^8 (9th bit is set)
            A ^= P          # perform modulo operation, XORing A with P

    # Handle case where T is larger than 8 bits
    while T.bit_length() > 8:
        excess = T.bit_length() - 8
        T ^= P << excess

    # Convert T back to a binary array of length 8
    return int_to_binary_array(T, 8)

def gf_inverse(A_dec, P):
    """
    Compute the multiplicative inverse of A(x) in GF(2^8).
    A_dec: Decimal representation of A(x).
    P: Irreducible polynomial P(x) in GF(2^m) (in binary format).
    """
    # Convert A(x) to a binary array
    A_array = decimal_to_binary_array(A_dec)

    # Set initial value S(x) = 1 in binary array format
    S_array = decimal_to_binary_array(1)

    D = 136  # Binary exponent

    # Binary representation of D
    D_bits = decimal_to_binary_array(D)

    # Iteratively perform multiplication for each bit in D
    for di in D_bits:
        # S(x) = S(x)^2 mod P(x)
        S_array = gf_multiply_fma(S_array, S_array, P)  # Note: removed redundant decimal_to_binary_array call
        if di == 1:
            # S(x) = S(x) * A(x) mod P(x)
            S_array = gf_multiply_fma(S_array, A_array, P)  # Same here
    
    # Convert S_array back to an integer and return as the multiplicative inverse
    return binary_array_to_int(S_array)


A_dec = 51
# D = 0b10011011
P = 0b100011011  # Irreducible polynomial P(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1

try:
    result = gf_inverse(A_dec, P)
    print(f"Result: {result} (in decimal)")
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

# Debugging outputs
print("A in decimal =", A_dec)
print("Result in decimal =", result


# 155 - 10011011`your text`

# tried using CHTGPT ... and modificaitons by myself. ```


What's the question here, or what part is not working

gf_inverse()  is not working correctly. i could not get the results.
